# Export resolution wrong when using Illustrator CC's Export to Screens

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to export images in the size 1536x2048 using the Export to Screens tool in Illustrator. However, when exporting some images are exported as 1537x2048 or 1537x2049. How do I make sure it is exported at the correct size? Also, in the Save for Web tool, there is a clip to artboards option. Are there any similar tools in the new Export for Screens that I can use to make sure the image is the correct size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the positions of your artboards on the canvas are at whole numbers.

If you have moved your art boards around they are probably sitting at arbitrary values like X=412.42 and Y=67.91. Just select the digits after the decimals and delete them.